# On a reference for computing global spectrum of $A_n$-curve singularities, by H.Dao and E.Faber

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay-rings

This question is about chasing down a reference in a paper relating to non-commutative crepant resolutions and Cohen-Macaulay representation theory.

Allow me to first give a minor introduction.

Let $(R, \mathfrak m)$ be a commutative complete local Cohen-Macaulay ring. For a finitely generated $R$-module $M$, let $\text{End}_R(M):=\text{Hom}_R(M,M)$ be the endomorphism ring (this ring is Noetherian, albeit non-commutative) . A finitely generated $R$-module $M$ is called maximal Cohen-Macaulay iff $\text{depth}(M)=\dim R$. For any ring $S$, let $\text{gl}.\dim (S)$ denote the global dimension of $S$

The global spectrum of $R$ is the set $$gs(R):=\{n\ge 0 :n=\text{gl}.\dim \text{End}_R(M); M \text{ is a maximal Cohen-Macaulay module over } R\}$$.

In https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2016.03.020 , section 4.2, the authors calculate the global spectrum of $A_n : k[[x,y]]/(x^2+y^n), n\ge 2$ , curve singularities using ladders and state that in the reference [11] the same characterization has been carried out using a general fact about triangulated categories, and I'd really like to know this alternative proof. So I look at the reference [11] and see that it is a paper in preparation by H.Dao and E.Faber , On global dimension of endomorphism rings. Now when I searched Google and arxiv with this title, nothing showed up.

Does anyone know if this paper referenced [11] has been made available yet ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you write to Dao at University of Kansas? He also may see your post here and answer it.

Comment: @Mohan: I am from a very small place and I really never have written to Professors at other Universities ever ... if Professor Dao is at Mathoverflow, then that's my best chance at getting a response ...

Comment: You could look him up on MO (Hailong Dao) and ping him.

Comment: @Mohan: how would I ping him ?

Comment: Exactly as you have pinged me here. Find his MO name prefix with the at symbol.

Comment: @Hailong Dao: Dear Professor Dao, would you be so kind enough to please provide an answer to this Question ? Thank you

Comment: @Mohan: I think I was able to do it. Thank you very much.